# Return Partial view inside search results rendering variant

Tags: sxa, content-search

I'm using `Sitecore 9.1.1 with SXA 1.8.1`.

I have a **search results component**, I need to render a partial view inside a section in its rendering variant.

I tried to add a **Variant component** for a custom controller rendering that returns the view. 
However, it gives me the below error:

[image]

I also tried to add a **Variant Template** and used an `NVelocity function` (as shown below) that returns an ActionResult.

[image]

However the ActionResult is rendered as an object, it's not rendered as HTML.

[image]

Is there any other way to render my partial view inside the search results rendering variant?

Comment: Why do need to render a partial view? They are not designed to do that..  What is your actual requirement? If we know that, we might help you with an alternative.

Comment: And don't use NVelocity.. ;)

Comment: That is the most crazy idea I have ever heard:) I think you need to do a step back an re-think the design of your project. And as @Gatogordo written - don't use NVelocity if you are not force to do it!